# Adding ripple to mat-card without the card expanding on click/touch

Tags: angular5, angular-material-5

Im trying to add a ripple effect to a card using angular material. The ripple effect works the way it supposed except that it expands the hight of the card when the effect is active. 
How can I stop the card from expanding?

```
<mat-card mat-ripple>
  <mat-card-content>This is content</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[Stackblitz that demonstrates the behaviour](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ripple-lab)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a class (i.e. last-child) to the last child of your mat-card (in your case mat-card-content) and define the following style:

```css
.mat-card .last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The problem is that matRipple adds an zero-height element to the mat-card while Angular Material only removes the margin-bottom from the last child.

Comment: Great, thanks. Solved the problem. (Stackblitz updated to demonstrate the fact)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when applied to a `<mat-card-actions>` element, but it seemingly does on the `<mat-card-content>` element. [See forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ripple-lab-bdjbqq). How does this solution change for this scenario?

Comment: If you have actions, as in 'mat-card-actions' for any buttons on the material card, make sure to include the .last-child class on this element instead of the content element. I also removed the padding from the mat-card-actions element using CSS, and this resolved the issue faced by https://stackoverflow.com/users/569531/mitch (mentioned above)

Answer (score 12):

If you add the footer element (with or without content) you won't need additional CSS and this will lock the height when activating the ripple effect.

```xml
<mat-card mat-ripple>
  <mat-card-content>This is content</mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-footer></mat-card-footer>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Even adding an empty footer eliminated the vertical expansion of the card.

Comment: This helped to fix the issue! Thank you.

Comment: saved a lot time , tnx!

Answer (score 4):

should be as easy as adding matRipple to the mat-card

```html
    <mat-card class="action-card" matRipple>
        <mat-card-title>
            {{content}}
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
          desc
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
```

make sure you inject the MatRippleModule into your module.ts though, that threw me off for a while

Comment: I may be missing something here but this code behaves in the exact same way. The card height expands when the ripple is applied.

Comment: I also noticed this behavior before, what happened to mine is that I gave a container height like 200px, but no height on mat-card, so when clicked it's trying to expend to container height. I then give card a height property in css, then the issue disapeared. @JonasAndreasson

Answer (score 2):

Use a div -Tag inside of mat-card -Tag. This Fix my issue.